# Integration, substitution?

Tags: integration

Let $$f(x)=\int_{\ln 2}^{x} \frac{e^t}{t} dt $$  and  let $c=1+\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$.

Express $$\int_{c}^{x} \frac{e^{2t}}{t-1} dt $$ in terms of $f$.

I have no idea where I should start with. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=t-1$. Then $du=dt$. This gives that $$\int_{c}^{x}\frac{e^{2t}}{t-1}=\int_{\frac{1}{2}ln2}^{x-1}\frac{e^{2u+2}}{u}du=e^{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}ln2}^{x-1}\frac{e^{2u}}{u}du$$

Now let $2u=s$. Hence $2du=ds$. So the integral now becomes $$e^{2}\int_{ln2}^{2x-2}\frac{e^{s}}{s}ds$$

Now $$f(2x-2)=\int_{ln2}^{2x-2}\frac{e^{t}}{t}$$

And Hence $$\int_{c}^{x}\frac{e^{2t}}{t-1}=e^2f(2x-2)$$